# tag an image with metadata so it can be externally managed in an apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to be able to insert an image into a docs Document that is subsequently managed by an apps-script.

In this example I might insert a skeleton (with WxH settings) example of what I intend to finally display like so;

[image]

But then add some interest later.

[image]

There seems to be a [setAttributes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_inlineimage#setAttributes) method for the [InlineImage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_inlineimage) class, but its not clear if any of those can be used to tag the image in such a way, that later I can iterate all the images in the doc, and update them as appropriate.

Comment: I'm also not sure about `setAttributes`. But do you need to tag an image manually after you insert it? Or are you going to insert via the script itself?

Comment: sorry, it would be part of the script itself. Basically I have a little chrome extension widget that would do the insert of the image. re setAttributes, it appears that any setAttributes that are not in the Attributes Enum are rejected, and any attributes that do not apply to InlineImages are silently discarded. At the moment the option that I am thinking of is to set metadata on the actual image files themselves via the png or jpeg specfication, but ive not had a chance to try that yet...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to attach arbitrary metadata or tags to an image element in Google Apps Script.